# Why isn't the read command showing in the output? (bash)

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following function in a bash script:

```
function use_selected(){
    clear
    echo " "
    echo -e "$color2 uwu$color1 Here you can edit your progress of this anime:"
    echo -e " $color2$(fzf --ansi | cut -d':' -f1)"
    echo -e "$color1 What's wrong whit this anime??"
    echo -e "$color2 Edit status$color1 (s)"
    echo -e "$color1 Edit total seasons$color2 (ts)"
    echo -e "$color2 Edit current season$color1 (cs)"
    echo -e "$color1 Edit total eps of current season$color2 (te)"
    echo -e "$color2 Edit current episode$color1 (ce)"
    echo -e "$color1 Edit rating$color2 (r)"
    echo -e "$color2 Edit name$color1 (n)"
    read -p " > " edit
}
```

And here's the output:

```
 uwu Here you can edit your progress of this anime:
 Chainsaw Man
 What's wrong whit this anime??
 Edit status (s)
 Edit total seasons (ts)
 Edit current season (cs)
 Edit total eps of current season (te)
 Edit current episode (ce)
 Edit rating (r)
 Edit name (n)
```

(It's an anime tracker script ok? =)) ignore the uwu )
I used the read command similarly more times in my script and it worked, but here it does'n
It doesn't work even after I add some if elif statements to use that edit variable

Comment: It works for me. After it prints `edit name (n)` it prints the `>` prompt.

Comment: Is `stderr` redirected when you call the function? The prompt is written to stderr, not stdout.

Comment: How do i check that?

Comment: Look for `2>` in the script. But I think you would know if you're doing it, it's not something that happens by accident.

Comment: If you get rid of all the `echo` statements do you see the read prompt?

Comment: No it still doesn't show

Comment: What if you just use `read -p '>' edit` outside the function?

Comment: This way it does lol

Comment: It makes no sense to me tho =))

Comment: Please post a [mre]. Something about the way you're calling the function is disabling its prompt output.

Comment: echo "$list_watching" | use_selected

Comment: then now i changed it to echo "$list_watching" | use_selected; read -p " > " edit and removed that line from the function

Comment: The prompt is only displayed if input is coming from a terminal. Since you're piping input to the function, it doesn't display the prompt.

Comment: Why do you need the prompt if you're  not answering the question by hand? The value of `$list_watching` will be used as the answer.

Comment: Now that u say that it makes total sense
I dumb sorry

Comment: Note that the `edit` variable won't be set in the main script when you do this. Pipelines are executed in a subshell, so variable assignments don't persist.

Comment: yes it does i tested it now by making another function that prints a if edit is a and added it to that line echo "$list_watching" | use_selected; read -p " > " edit; a

Comment: That `read` isn't inside the pipeline. You can see the problem if you do `echo "$list_watching" | read -p " > " edit` then `echo "$edit"`